# Magento2 How to get login, Register and whishlist links

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I need to modify Magento2 `form.mini.phtml` to have Login, Register and Wishlist links. And after wishlist link, I need to display product count which are in the wishlist after login.

I know how to do this on Magento 1x but I'm confused how to get them on Magento 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login link: `$this->getUrl("customer/account/login")`
Register link: `$this->getUrl('customer/account/create')`

For the Wishlist link with product count:

```
<span data-bind="scope: 'wishlist'" class="link wishlist">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('wishlist') ?>">
        <?php echo __('My Wishlist') ?>
        <!-- ko if: wishlist().counter --><span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span><!-- /ko -->
    </a>
</span>
```

You need to use this code: `<!-- ko if: wishlist().counter --><span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span><!-- /ko -->`
to show product count (don't remove it)

If you have removed the Wishlist link on top links, you need to add this javascript code (if not, ignore it):

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "wishlist": {
                    "component": "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it worked well , thanks is there any way to customise wishlist count current it is "x Items" but I need to display it as "(x)" items